# useTranslation from react-i18next with json returns the key

Tags: json, react-i18next

I am using "useTranslation" with the following json:

```
{
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": {
        "City": "London"
    }
}
```

in react component I use the `const {t} = useTranslation();` , but when I try to

```
{t('Language')}<br/>
{t('Country.City')}
```

it shows "Country.City" instead of "London", it is working for Language but not for Country.City

```
English
Country.City
```

does anyone have an idea how to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution if someone have the same problem :-).
in i18n.ts the keySeparation was "false" -> keys can't be nested
now I made `keySeparator : '.'` and it's working

Comment: HI @Ayoub, can you please add example of your above answer? Thanks.